# oracle 32 bit client on a windows 7 64 bit computer

Tags: windows-7-x64, oracle9i

Trying to install Oracle 9i (32bit) client on a Windows 7 64bit computer.  Seems to install fine, but when trying to run anything, such as the Net Configuration Assistant, it doesn't do anything, no errors, and nothing started in the background.

So the question is:

Can the 32 bit client of Oracle be installed on a 64 bit Windows 7 PC?  Or does it need to be a 64 bit client?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a 32 bit client, and if your software is 32 bit, you **need** to install the 32 bit client to use it, even on a 64 bit system.